# Batch process - image into different size and angle images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing

I have a lot of monitor images for an e-commerce website - all the images have a path already created with the selection of the screen. now my issue is that each monitor has different views and they are different sizes as well.

is there a way to have a preselected image fit into these screens paths and also adjust the perspective to fit the path?

Thank you, i really do not want to spend so much time and energy into changing all these screens - let me know if any more info is needed to solve this.

Comment: or just help with this part would be really helpful - 

is there a way to match the image perspective to the one from the path?

Comment: could you please provide a sample for more clarity ....

Answer (score 1):

Unless all of the monitors have the same aspect ratio, then this won't work.

You could run a couple of scripts to extract the positions of each path's nodes and then use that information to transform an image and composite it on top of the monitor. But if you can't tell the script what the image should look like if the screen were 'flat', then it will look distorted.

If all of the monitors *are* of roughly the same ratio, then modifying [this script](https://github.com/pdizz/Photoshop-Scripts/blob/master/get%20selection%20coordinate%20points.jsx) can give you the coordinates of each node of a path in each file. If the coordinates are all in the same order (starting topLeft and going clockwise, for example), those coordinates can then be used in [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/) to distort the image you want to be shown in the monitor. Maybe you could also use a Photoshop script to transform them, i'm not sure.